# No appropriate type product is found (Woocommerce and WPML)

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, wpml

I am translating a website from english to german. The main issue arises when you visit a page in german an error message says: 
"No appropriate type product is found."

Anyone encountered this error before?
thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for sure you need woocommerce-multilingual extension.

If you have  more questions, try to ask at official forum: https://wpml.org/forums/